# Background Gradients and transparent 3d plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, gradient

I'm trying to reproduce this graphic using `pgfplots`. Before I get too involved though, I wanted to make sure it's actually possible. At this point, I have no idea how to get the background gradient surfaces or the transparent curved 3d plot. Any help with that would be great!

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[
  view={110}{30},
  ticks=none,
  axis lines=center,
  xmin=0,xmax=20,ymin=0,ymax=20,zmin=0,zmax=20,
  xlabel={size diversity},ylabel={functional role},zlabel={functional response},
]

\addplot3 coordinates {(8,15,20)} node[above] {PICO} {(8,8,12)} node[above] {COCCO} {(3,3,3)} node[above] {PHAEO} {(8,15,1)} node[above] {DIAZO} {(18,10,1)} node[above] {DIATOM};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend you don't do this overpainted plot. The axis shadings have zero effect on understanding the data. And the axis labels are stuff that only a mother can love. It is *in theory* possible to do this though

Comment: @percusse Without the gradients then. Am I using the right technology here (`\addplot3 coordinates ...`) or would you recommend something different? Do you know how best to produce the white lines from the spheres to the gradient surfaces?

Comment: remove `axis lines=center` and use `\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, opacity=0.5,domain=0.0001:1, domain y=0.00001:1] (x,y,{2*(x-.5)^2+3*(y-.5)^2});` to get an intial plot. Then you can place markers and other cosmetics from there. I just made the function up. You can also approximate the function.|Looks like a parabolic function viewed fom origin